# How to change status of woocommerce orders when post status is changed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a custom post type in wordpress called appointment. Whenever someone books a product in woocommerce a new apppointment is created. The appoinment has 3 status Publish, Draft and Pending Review. What i want to achieve is when i change the status of any appoinment the order status of the product linked to that changes. For example if i change the appointment status to draft the order status become cancelled. I have been trying to figure this out but am really struggling. Please help me out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hook into `transition_post_status` action to add custom code before the post status of an appointment post type is changed.

In the example below I am checking if the post_type of changed post is '*appointment*' (please replace it with your post status slug). Then I am trying to get *WC_Order* object (assuming the linked order ID is stored as a post meta `linked_order_id` for each appointment, you didn't specify this in your question). If the order is found I am setting the order status based on the post status of the appointment.

```
function update_order_status_by_appointment( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    // Perform only for 'appointment' post type
    if( get_post_type( $post ) === 'appointment' ) {

        // Get WC_Order linked to this appointment
        $order_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'linked_order_id', true);
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Check if order with this ID exists
        if( $order ) {

            // If appointment is being changed to 'draft', change order status to 'cancelled'
            if( $new_status === 'draft' ) {
                $order->update_status('cancelled');
            }

            // Add other conditions as you wish
            // ...
        }
    }
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'update_order_status_by_appointment', 10, 3);
```

Code goes in functions.php of your active child-theme or theme. It is not tested though, but it should work.